# Mockito: When is @Mock object get initialized and which constructor it calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jmockit

I'm trying to figure out how mockito is working behind in order to debug. I was wondering for the object with @Mock annotation, when is it initialized? Like, before @Before or after @Before?

And if there're several different constructors, how is mockito determines which constructors to call?

And if I use jmockit @Mocked instead, are there any different answers of the questions above?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you trying to debug something with Mockito?

Comment: I'm facing some intermittent "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" with a class in JNI. Thus I suspect that when mockito/jmockit tries to initialize an object, sometimes the JNI dependency in order to initialize that object somehow doesn't work correctly. So I'd like to know when do mockito and jmockit initialize them, and see if there's any chance I can mock the JNI call with MockUp somewhere before initialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mock* objects created with Mockito don't call any constructor or static initializer. (This is achieved through [Objenesis](http://objenesis.org/) in older versions of Mockito, and [ByteBuddy](http://bytebuddy.net/#/) in newer versions.) Consequently, all of the fields are uninitialized, and no side effects in constructors happen at all including any exceptions you might see thrown.

In contrast, *spy* objects [do have their constructors called](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Spy.html). Mockito will default to calling a no-argument constructor (public or private) if you don't initialize the field, and you can call the constructor of your choice inside the initializer.

The order of @Mock annotation initialization depends on which technique you use to initialize mocks:

- If you use [`MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html), mocks are initialized [after initializer blocks, constructors, and @Rules, and before any other @Befores](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/runners/SilentJUnitRunner.java#L26) as defined in [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java#L297).
- If you use [`MockitoRule`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html), mocks are initialized before any @Before methods, but in [undefined order compared to other @Rules](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html) unless you [chain them manually with `RuleChain`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html).
- If you use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()`, mocks are initialized exactly when you call that method, which is after initializer blocks and rules, and (if you call within a @Before method) in undefined order compared to other @Before methods.

Comment: AFAICT, MockitoRule is a MethodRule, not a TestRule, so it can't be used in a RuleChain.

Answer (score 2):

`@Mocked` fields are initialized right after the test class is instantiated by the test runner (JUnit, TestNG), before any `@Before`/`@BeforeMethod`-annotated methods get executed.

The mocked instance is created by JMockit without calling any constructor in the mocked class.

The above answers also apply to Mockito (and any other mocking library with similar features).